# Get just one part of NSIndexPath while using indexPathsForVisibleItems

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, xcode4.5

I'm new to Obj-C. I've been working with a sorting feature of a UICollectionView. I'm saving the data after the cells have shifted around. However the NSIndexPath information is not as I would have expected. I'm not sure how I can access just one part of the index when using indexPathsForVisibleItems.

```
NSArray *visible = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
NSLog(@"These are the visible cells %@", visible);
```

This returns NSLogs like this....

```
"<NSIndexPath 0x8a6b7f0> 2 indexes [0, 0]",
"<NSIndexPath 0x8a6d3d0> 2 indexes [0, 2]",
"<NSIndexPath 0x8a6d480> 2 indexes [0, 3]",
"<NSIndexPath 0x889f080> 2 indexes [0, 1]"
```

I want to get the second column of numbers. The 0,2,3,1 out of the NSIndex path. I'm sure if I can just access those values I can then get information out of the cell. Is there a particular convention or conversion to get 0,2,3,1 and into an simple array.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like...

```
NSArray *visible = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
NSMutableArray *rowsArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[visible count]];
[visible enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSIndexPath *indexPath, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
  [rowsArray addObject:@(indexPath.item)];
}];
```

That will give you an array of `NSNumber` objects representing all the item values from the indexPaths in your visible items.

If you're using this from a `UICollectionView` you shouldn't really use the `.row` property of the `NSIndexPath`, as this is intended for use with a `UITableView`. [NSIndexPath UIKit Additions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) for reference on this point.

Comment: WOW! Pasted it right in and it worked like a charm. I bet I can get the info I want now that I have that second half of the index out. Much appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: I'm new to stackoverflow. I certainly will. =)

Answer (score 2):

```
NSMutableArray * array = [NSMutableArray array];
NSArray * arr = [self.collectionView indexPathsForVisibleItems];
for(NSIndexPath * path in arr) {
   [array addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:path.section]];
   //(or)
   [arr addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:path.row]];
}
```